# High trafic: website crash and error

Tags: apache

Since 1 week, my website crashes 1 or 2 times a hour.
The message error is:

`504 gateway time-out - nginx`

Then it crashes again. This problem appears when I edit something in the admin panel. For exemple if I create a new post, the website crashes.

In adition, sometimes I get this error on random pages:

[image]

RAM and CPU are not overloaded (I have 16 cores and 128 GB). Max. CPU is about 2 and max. RAM load is about 8 GB.

The problem appears whereas I don't make anny modification on the website since few days.

I have only 150 visitors per minute. Before, I had 1000 visitors per minute with CloudFlare and no problem, the site was really fast and no errors, but now I have deactive it because it makes the website crash.

I have changed `ServerLimit` and `MaxClients` to `1000` in `httpd.conf` and `worker_connections` to `10240` in `nginx.conf`, but that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: You should try to check your error logs.

Comment: Do you use an IDE?  In that IDE, have you checked your PHP for errors?

Answer (score 1):

Please check to see if your server is faulting because of maxed entry processes (or subsiquent virtual memory limit). This means that too many people are requesting and scripts aren't fast enough to catch up, or scripts are still running (held) for another user. By opening more entry processes or vram, this may resolve a 500/502/503/504. Normally, economy servers are set to something like 20 entry processes in cPanel "out of the box". With your traffic, they could cap easily if set below 40.

If its happening on a regular basis, it could be a clue that some automation (like Googlebot) is requesting a large script (like a big sitemap or feed) on a regular basis. Sometimes Googlebot is impatient and nails the url 2-4 times within seconds, resulting in extra processes held until a thread is cleared to generate other site scripts.

By logging long or resource intensive scripts such as feeds, you can further deduce if it is a performance bottleneck to your server. Often caching can help. If you need a server side app that helps to mitigate resource caps like these, and you run CentOS, check out CloudLinux LVE https://cloudlinux.com/

Hope that helps!